# Highchart plot from two vectors: split the vectors?

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I want to plot data points with the attributes 'value' and 'date'. Problem is, the format is data: `[[...], [...]]` where the first bracket is, say, 'value' and the second 'date'. I'd like to know how to split the two vectors, that is, take one value from each vector and put it into that format to create a data point. Perhaps there's some other way to do this?

'values' are stored as `$data[] = $row['value'];`
'date' are stored as `$data2[] = $row['date'];`

Fully working code with only one working vector 'value' down below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>My first column chart by Highcharts</title>
        <!-- 1. Add JQuery and Highcharts in the head of your page -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

        <!-- 2. You can add print and export feature by adding this line -->
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


        <!-- 3. Add the JavaScript with the Highchart options to initialize the chart -->
        <script type="text/javascript">


<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("sensordb", $con);
$result=mysql_query('select value, date from data');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $data[] = $row['value'];
    $data2[] = $row['date'];

}
?>


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]
        }]
    });
});


</script>


    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- 3. Add the container -->
        <div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>      

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am unclear on the actual question. Why are you creating two arrays, if your goal is to make one array with date/value pairs?

Comment: Because I don't know how else to do it. I could put it into one array, but how do I split the data from the array then. It'll be rendered as several points of the same type i.e 'date' and 'value' will be plotted on the x-axis as if were the same type.

Comment: What do you want this chart to actually look like? You want date as one series, and values as another? that's very unusual.  But if that's your goal, what about your current set up is not working? It looks like you're creating two arrays, one of your dates, one of your values

Comment: Let me rephrase.. I want to plot data points (x, y) where y is value and x is time. If instead of data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>] I plot data: [[<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>], [<?php echo join($data2, ',') ?>]] i will only get one data point..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your comments, you need your data in the standard format of

```
data: [[date,value],[date,value]...]
```

Which is a very different thing from splitting the data into two arrays. :)

Take this:

```
$data[] = $row['value'];
$data2[] = $row['date'];
```

And change it to this:

```
$data[] = array($row['date'],$row['value']);
```

Keep in mind that your dates will need to be in epoch format, as milliseconds, and you will need to json_encode the array.

You'll also need to make sure your values are numeric, by casting them to either integers or floats, depending on which they are expected to be.

You can get the date and value in the right format like this:

```
$data[] = array(
   strtotime($row['date']) * 1000, //convert to epoch time, multiply for milliseconds
   (float)$row['value']  //cast value as a float; use (int) to cast as integer
);
```

When you add the data to the chart, try it this way:

```
series:[{
  data: <?echo json_encode($data); ?>
}]
```

(note that I do not include the brackets - the json_encode() does that already)

Comment: I get the output "[[934920422000,1]][[934920422000,1],[935006822000,2]][[934920422000,1],[935006822000,2],[935093222000,3]][[934920422000,1],[935006822000,2],[935093222000,3],[935179622000,4]][[934920422000,1],[935006822000,2],[935093222000,3],[935179622000,4]," when I echo json_encode($data); so it should work fine but it doesn't seem to want to plot the data when using data: <?echo json_encode($data); ?> . There are some double brackets in $data i.e "..]][[.." perhaps this might cause it

Comment: or perhaps it's due to the format i.e data: [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]] that is, I need a comma in between each bracket

Comment: the format should be: data: [ [date,value], [date, value], [date, value] ] the entire array wrapped in one set of brackets, and each x,y pair wrapped in its own set of brackets, separated by a comma. As far as I can see, the code I provided should result in exactly that.

Comment: I don't know what I changed but it works now! thanks alot